# Any way to get meaningful errors in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using Ember CLI and I have a problem in my code which is related to computed aliases and model relationships. I'm not able to debug this problem as I'm getting messed up errors like this:

```
"EmberError@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:22707:15
Ember.default.assert@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:15408:13
ember$data$lib$system$store$finders$$_find/<@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:63941:9
tryCatch@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:55993:16
invokeCallback@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:56005:17
publish@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:55976:11
@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:37026:7
Queue.prototype.invoke@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11432:11
Queue.prototype.flush@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11497:13
DeferredActionQueues.prototype.flush@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11302:13
Backburner.prototype.end@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:10727:11
Backburner.prototype.run@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:10782:15
executeTimers@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11164:7
updateLaterTimer/backburner._laterTimer<@http://localhost/assets/vendor.js:11153:11
"
```

Is there any way to get nicer errors? Even plain javascript exceptions would be better than this.

I have this in the console:

```
"DEBUG: -------------------------------" vendor.js:15442:4
"DEBUG: Ember      : 1.12.0" vendor.js:15442:4
"DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.17" vendor.js:15442:4
"DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3" vendor.js:15442:4
"DEBUG: -------------------------------"
... Some deprecations messages from Ember Data that is irrelevant
"Ember Inspector Active"
... The error above
```

Comment: Do you have the ember inspector installed?

Comment: You mean the Firefox addon? Yes I do.

Comment: And that's all that gets dumped in the console?

Comment: I've added everything to the question. Basically yes that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an ember app that has been built for production...

To debug the app run `ember server`

You will then get source mapped output

Comment: I'm running the app using `ember serve`. It's not production code.

Comment: That is v odd... Not sure why you get different output - you should be getting better logging that that

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, and to be honest I don't think there's a way to get better stack traces.

Your best bet is to try and add breakpoints using `debugger;` where you have a hunch the error is unfolding, and then inspecting the code at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is because a bug on Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=670002 . On my development environment, the console.log show the vendor.js line number (non-desired), but through debugging I see the sources of my project.

Have you tried to debug the sources? In the debugger tab it should show all your application files and some from different addons. I've got ember 2.4.4.